# how to share svn repository between two computers

Tags: svn, repository

On my workstation I have SVN repository. I use it on both workstation and laptop. On workstation I can access repository locally, but on laptop I have to be internet-connected to access repository. This is not convenient, because I can not work from plane/trains and other internet-less places (i want to compare revisions etc etc.).

It would be much more comfortable to have the COPY of the svn repository on laptop, but I need up to date copy.

The most trivial solution would be to store svn repository in cloud like https://www.dropbox.com so anytime repository is updated on one computer it would be updated on another computer.

But I do not want to use dropbox because of security reasons, I don't want to store confidential files somewhere in internet, and likely unencrypted.

What else can I do? I want to synchronize two copies of repository automatically, but I do not want to store it in internet. Probably laptop itself every time internet appears should "get" up to date copy from workstation and every time repository is updated on laptop it should commit new revision to workstation automatically?

I understand that SVN is not designed to do such things, but as I am the only commiter to repository and I only have workstation and laptop we can assume that conflict never occurs...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move over to a distributed version control system like git or Mercurial. Subversion is made to have one central repository in one place. Trying to replicate the repo itself would mean a great risk of data loss or inconsitencies.

Comment: I fully satisfied with svn. And storing svn in dropbox will solve all my problems except security. There is only one commiter to repository and this is me!

Comment: You're fully satisfied, yet you need  to somehow move the repository between different PCs. And DVCS let you do that without any headaches - you'll be just moving a folder on a usb stick.

Answer (score 0):

Why you not try source code hosting like [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) ? They have private repositories too.

Comment: i hever heard about it. but i don't like idea of storing repository somewhere in internet unencrypted

Comment: So.. if you don't like, you must give a try with dvcs like git or mercurial like @Anders Abel say :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are really dead-set on keeping a copy of your repository in two places (which, as others have pointed out, is strange, but it's your life), you could always encrypt your repository locally after each commit and put that up on dropbox. Whenever you need to switch to your laptop, just grab the dropbox version and unencrypt it. I guess you would have to keep overwriting your repositories in each location each time you do an update, but otherwise, it seems to do what you want.

Comment: how can I do that automatically? can visualsvn server encript itself and would this be secure?

Comment: @javapowered - it's not in any way function of VisualSVN Server. If you want something **very unusual** from it - you can **place order and buy** needed functionality