# Migrating an SVN repository to some distributed VCS (Git or Mercurial)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, svn, mercurial

From [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9962884/67988) I understood that I have to change my SVN repository to a distributed VCS.

So, currently, I:

- have an existing SVN repository,
- use Visual Studio 2010,
- use VisualSVN for both client and server.

I want to:

- convert both client and server sides to a distributed VCS,
- keep the history,
- still have a handy Visual Studio plugin for the new VCS.

My questions:

- What VCS is better to use?
- How to convert the repository from SVN to another VCS?
- On client side, I should likely just "recheckout" using new VCS plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a positive experience of transitioning from a centralized VCS (Team Foundation Server) to Mercurial, via SVN. So I guess this is applicable to your case.

[`hg convert`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) can convert your SVN repository into a Mercurial one, keeping history and branches (provided you were sticking to the usual branch/tag layout in SVN).

[TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) provides excellent integration of Mercurial features into Windows Explorer, along with the visual tools like DAG renderer, source tree browsing, and annotate/blame tools. And the same time, TortoiseHg keeps the command-line `hg` program, so you're free to mix the GUI and the CLI.

[VisualHG](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/), being based on TortoiseHg, integrates Mercurial repository support into Visual Studio 2008/2010, adding, removing and renaming your solution files as you make changes in the Solution Explorer.

This set of tools provides quite good support for most medium-to-large projects. However, if your project is very large, or it contains a lot of big (tens on megabytes) binary files (say, media), or you plan to regularly put built binaries under source control, this might render Mercurial hard to use.

In this case, you might want to use additional tools, like Mercurial subrepositories and largefiles extensions, or consider another VCS (Git).

Comment: i have several binary files in repository. biggest one is 13 MB. why this is problem for Mercurial?

Comment: @javapowered: Mercurial handles all files in-memory, and the processing has certain overhead. It might simply choke on a 100 MB file, see also http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HandlingLargeFiles. At the same time, having a number of ~10 MB files is not a problem. However, if you plan to put large files in your repo on a regular basis, this means the repo will be growing larger and larges over time, and every repo is stored locally. Trimming history is not supported in Mercurial, as of now.

Comment: probably I should just use git then?

Comment: @javapowered: Well, I have ~300 binaries in my repo (mostly DLLs), some of them with history, the largest being ~45 MB, average 2-3 MB, and Mercurial works fine. I guess this can be a baseline for you. However, for an additional set of libraries, 250 MB total, I've chosen to use a subrepository.

Comment: @javapowered: Git repositories will experience the same growth, as will SVN repositories for that matter (just not local checkouts). It simply needs to store them for you to be able to reproduce their earlier versions, and usually those type of files won’t be able to benefit much from delta compression.

Comment: It is simple math, if you check in a different 10 MB file ten times, the repository size will be 100 MB. As long as the binary files aren’t too sizable and you only change them infrequently, I wouldn’t worry about it.

Comment: @LaurensHolst: Being a Mercurial user myself, I can't help but state that `git repack -ad` is more efficient in storing a number of different versions of a binary file, in comparison to the Mercurial revlog.

Comment: @Helgi: Surely if the contents of the file is random (e.g. for compressed zip, jar or png files) there is no way to store them more efficiently than their collective size? And if it’s a more easily compressed format, afaik Mercurial also applies delta compression and zips binaries... I wonder what repack does differently.

Comment: @LaurensHolst: I have only a surface knowledge of the Mercurial internals, but I believed that revlogs are basically deltas. Doesn't this mean that if I have file A in rev 1, then a modified version B of it in rev 2, and then the reverted A in rev 3, Mercurial will store `A` in r1, `B-A` in r2, and `A-B` in r3?

Comment: @Helgi: As far as I know, as long as storing the delta is smaller than storing the full file, and the distance from the full file isn’t too far, yes.

Comment: @Helgi: But if the file’s hash matches the hash of a previous one, I imagine it would not store it again...

Comment: @LaurensHolst: I haven't dug the revlogs et al. that deep, but I did a couple of experiments with large Word documents (`.doc` ones), and Git's compression proved to be a little more efficient.

Comment: @Helgi: If I understand tonfa correctly in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892125/i-cant-find-the-code-for-diff-binary-in-mercurial-source-code, Mercurial does not have an optimised binary diff algorithm, and does the binary comparison based on segments in the binary file separated by 0x0A bytes (the newline character). That might account for some inefficiency in certain specific cases. Though it wouldn’t matter for any kind of semi-random binary data, such as any compressed format (`zip`, `png`, `jar`, `odf`, etc.).