# I can't find the code for diff binary in mercurial source code

Tags: mercurial, diff, binary-diff

I am reading source code of mercurial,but what I saw in bdiff.c and mdiff.py is processing text, not binary.but they said mercurial treat all files as binary.I am confused.

Comment: Please ask this kind of question on mercurial-devel@selenic.com instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bdiff.c` and `mdiff.py` both works perfectly fine on binary files. They won't give you optimal diffs since they rely on the presence of newlines, but they work correctly (you won't lose any data).